# Even if I wrote \begin{figure}[!ht], my image goes to the wrong place

Tags: graphics

Here is my code:

```
    \subsubsection{Ionisation}
       \begin{figure}[!ht]
            \centering
            \includegraphics{SchémaIonisation.jpg}
            \caption{}
            \label{}
        \end{figure}

    \subsubsection{Ionosphère}
        \begin{figure}[!ht]
            \centering
            \includegraphics{SchémaIonosphère.jpg}
            \caption{}
            \label{}
        \end{figure}

    \subsubsection{En pratique}
```

My images are supposed to go where I put them in my code. However, they go in `\subsubsection{En pratique}`. I don't understand why since I wrote `[!ht]`. I am working on Overleaf.

[image]

[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2388 to understand how floats are placed.

Comment: It appears that the Ionisation figure is too large to fit in the remaining space on the page.  Therefore it will be held for the first available space on the next page.

Comment: Especially the answer that begins "do not use a floating environment if you do not want it float."

Comment: Thanks a lot, the package "float" and the add of the parameter [H] worked !